# Create Wallet Contract - Spinning for 2 days now

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have the ethereum wallet, created some test tokens, and then tried a wallet contract, single owner...named it and clicked create and entered the password.  Now I have the Wallet Contract spinning on my main page, saying "Creating", and it has been two days now, and this is after having stopped and rebooted a few times.

Is there a way to cancel this wallet contract?  It seems to be blocking any transfers of the test token now.

Comment: Are you using mainnet or testnet? From your description it can be you have set the transaction fee very low.

Comment: I somehow got it stopped by switching to the testnet and back to main...I think I restarted the wallet a few times before that.

Answer (score 1):

I did stop and restart the wallet, and switched between mainnet and ropsten twice...and transactions that were pending in the wallet (but confirmed on the blockchain) finally cleared and the wallet contract was created.  Then I could resume using the wallet.